# Link clickable area larger than its image?

Tags: css, image, hyperlink

I have searched for quite a bit and tried lots of stuff to fix this issue, including hiding the overflow in css.

I have an image that is linked to a video, for which the clickable area overextends the image, but only on the right side.

Relevant class: .overflow a (this was added as an attempt to fix from another answer)

Why is this clickable area so large, and how do I make it the same size as the image it encapsulates?

Firebug doesn't show anything out of the ordinary..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is displayed as block, so it takes up the full width of the parent. You'r solution would be this.

```
.overflow img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding below CSS code:

```
.overflow {
    display: inline-block;
}
```